# Properly parsing JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I would like to get the key/value pairs from a returned JSON string; based on my attempt, what am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var json_url = "http://hudsonspine.com/ldn/ldn.json";
  var json_str = $.getJSON(json_url);
  var json_strfy = JSON.stringify(json_str);
  var json_to_obj = $.parseJSON(json_str);
  console.log(json_to_obj.animal);  
});
```

I get the following error (which I'm assuming means not properly format data, even though my JSON source seems Ok):

```
"jQuery.Deferred exception: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (pen.js:13:21)
    at j (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:29948)
    at k (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:30262)" undefined
```

Comment: `$.getJSON(json_url);` is an async call - so your next line is being executed before `getJSON` is finished.

Comment: once you get past the whole asynchronous issue, and figuring out how $.getJSON actually works - `json_str` will actually be a javascript object - why would you stringify it - saving it as json_strfy? and clearly trying to parse a javascript object, using jquery's inferior parseJSON, will fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getJSON` doesn't return the JSON as a result. It's an asynchronous function, and the result is passed to the callback. It's already parsed (that's the only difference between `$.get` and `$.getJSON`), so you don't need to use functions like `$.parseJSON`

```
$.getJSON($json_url, function(result) {
    console.log(result.animal);
});
```